# vscode running all junit tests instead of just tagged tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, junit, tags

I'm trying to use tags for my junit tests, but all of my unit tests are being run anyway by vscode. I've tried reading the documentation for the test runner for java extension, which had me add the following to my settings.json:

```
    "java.test.Config": {
    "name": "default",
    "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "testKind": "junit",
    "filters.tags": [
        "group2",
    ]
}
```

Even after adding this to my settings.json, vscode still runs all of the tests

```
  @Test
  @Tag("group1")
  void test1() {
    assertEquals(1, 1);
  }

  @Test
  @Tag("group2")
  void test2() {
    assertEquals(2, 2);
  }

  @Test
  @Tag("group2")
  void test3() {
    assertEquals(3, 3);
  }
```

[Testing Tab in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w63xO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test/wiki/Run-with-Configuration) I think `filters` should be an object, like this:

```
"java.test.config": {
    "name": "default",
    "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "testKind": "junit",
    "filters": {
        "tags": [
            "group2"
        ]
    }
}
```